# Facebook recently changed the way they handle picture in events. How do i get the event picture after those changes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

Facebook recently changed the way they handle pictures in event. 
Now you can upload a photo which will be displayed when you post an event to someone's wall or in a group and that you can use as a cover.

How do i get that image?

Before i was using this query

```
        $fql[$id] =
            "SELECT
                eid,
                name,
                description,
                start_time,
                end_time,
                venue,
                location,
                update_time,
                has_profile_pic,
                pic_big
            FROM
                event
            WHERE
                eid IN ($imploded_eids) AND start_time > $time";
```

but right now pic_big is returning for most of the events just [image]
what should i do?

EDIT - i get that image for new events even if i use event_id/picture as you can see from this event 546510352049607/picture which has a cover photo https://www.facebook.com/events/546510352049607/

EDIT2 - i also opened a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/175306732618524) on facebook for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated field for the cover photo:

```
pic_cover (struct): Cover picture of Event
```

> SELECT pic_cover FROM event WHERE eid=546510352049607

The `pic_cover` might give `null` but [this is another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152316/fql-event-pic-cover-returns-null). Problem solved, otherwise this question is a duplicate.

Comment: ok thanks, is this documented somwhere?because in the graph explorer the pic_cover field is not present. 
Is the fact that pic_cover returns null a confirmed Facebook bug?

Comment: Here is the [source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) and here is the [Facebook bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/149447668550976).